# tf.gradients() won't work with 'tf.assign()', but works with '='

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, autograd

In a simple code below, gradient gets computed correctly.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.Variable(tf.ones_like(x), dtype=tf.float32)

y = 2*x
grad = tf.gradients(y, x)

ini = tf.global_variables_initializer()


with tf.Session() as ses:
    ses.run(ini)
    print(ses.run(grad))
```

The result, as expected, is `[array([ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.], dtype=float32)]`.
I get into problem when trying to use `tf.assign` for function computation. The below code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.Variable(tf.ones_like(x), dtype=tf.float32)

func = tf.assign(y, 2*x)
grad = tf.gradients(y, x)

ini = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as ses:
    ses.run(ini)
    ses.run(func)
    print(ses.run(grad))
```

... yields an error:

> TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type `<class 'NoneType'>`.

Why is that so? Is the connection between `x` and `y` node somehow "lost" via the `tf.assign` operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example, there's no dependency between `x` and `y`. `func` is an op that *depends on both* and happens to modify `y`. If you inspect the corresponding `tf.assign` op, you'll see:

```
op: "Assign"
input: "Variable"   # this is y
input: "mul"        # this is 2*x
```

But `x` and `y` are independent, that's why the engine fails to take the gradient.

Comment: Maxim, thank you for your answer! Can I ask for one more clarification? In case of gradient computation, should I typically expect a function not to be a graph node, just like in my first piece of code above? That is a bit counter-intuitive, as I was assuming that the graph should hold all the key computations... It gets me a bit confused what should and what should not be in the graph.

Comment: @Broono in terms of tensorflow, each node is an *operation* (short: op). The variable is also a set of ops: read/write/init. What you think of a *function* is a higher-level abstraction. So it's better to say it this way: assign op is a graph node, and you can run it.

Comment: I see... apparently I need to work on mapping of logical flow on graph architecture. Thank you for your answers!